# Is it possible to create something like local html template similar to React?

Tags: angular

For example I have something like this

```
<div class="leader">
    <div class="person">
        <div class="firstname">{{leader.firstName}}</div>
        <div class="lastname">{{leader.lastName}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="people">
        <div *ngFor="let person of people" class="person">
            <div class="firstname">{{person.firstName}}</div>
            <div class="lastname">{{person.lastName}}</div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Is it possible to reuse this code

```
<div class="person">
    <div class="firstname">{{person.firstName}}</div>
    <div class="lastname">{{person.lastName}}</div>
</div>
```

without creating a whole component?

For example in React a function can be used for this

```
function renderPerson(person){
    return (
    <div class="person">
        <div class="firstname">person.firstName</div>
        <div class="lastname">person.lastName</div>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you wanna reuse html you need a component, it's really easy and fast to do: `ng g component person` add `@input() person: Person;`, copy-paste your html and you're all set.

Comment: not sure if it works but have you tried just to target the same html file I mean in component b templateUrl: '../a/a.component.html' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ngTemplateContainer and ng-template

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Myxo3mkWYagEJutPJMMy).

```
<ng-template #reusable let-person="person">
{{person.firstName}} - {{person.lastName}}
</ng-template>

<h3>Leaders</h3>

<div *ngFor="let leader of leaders">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="reusable; context:{person: leader}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Great article [here](https://www.codeday.top/2017/06/23/30954.html)